# Wiki search options

Tags: search, filter, wiki

For example I have 2 wiki pages. First page includes such keywords as AD.180, AD.159, AD.200, second page includes keywords AD.300, AD.180, AD.159. If I search for AD.300 it displays me all pages which have AD before the number. Search doesn't take the AD.300 as a whole word, it searches for everything what has AD, not only AD.300.

How do I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes to find exact phrases. If you want to learn about "AD.300" and don't want a bunch of results that include documents that include the word. This tells the search engine to find the exact phrase inside the quotes.
Look about more nice tips about search http://www.networkworld.com/article/2222853/microsoft-subnet/10-essential-sharepoint-search-hints.html

Comment: This helped me a little, thanks. But if I have AD.180 in one page and AD 180 in another and if I search "AD.180" it still find me both pages, not the one where AD.180 is written.

Comment: Than I guess you have to use OR function
"AD.180" or "AD 180"

Comment: OR you just can search twice about it.